# karma disregards browser and reporter settings

Tags: gruntjs, teamcity, jasmine, karma-runner

I am running karma with grunt and I am using the advice from the karma-runner page how to configure it to watch on changed files:

> Config your watch task to run the karma task with the :run flag. For example:
>   ...
>   In your terminal window run $ grunt karma:unit:start watch,

tests are run and everything is fine except for the fact that karma starts reporting in the console in teamcity format (and I have it nowhere in the settings or dependencies) and insists on using PhantomJs regardless what settings I put in the browser array.

What could be causing that behavior?

Comment: It would help to see the relevant section(s) from your Gruntfile.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem is missing explicit port value in the karma conf